# How to compile gcc for riscv target and arm build

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, riscv

I want to compile gcc to be execute on a ARM core and generate riscv assembly. The idea is to build a cross-compiler for raspberry pi 4.
I tried to build the cross compile toolchain directly from the raspberry but it's too slow and crashed. So i want to build it from my x86 machine.
I tried to compile gcc by changing CC variable to an arm cross compiler but it didn't work. I found out you can specify a build and target option to build gcc :

```
./configure --build=arm-linux-gnueabi --target=riscv32-*-elf --prefix=/opt/riscv
```

I tried also that :

```
./configure --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=riscv32-unknown-elf --prefix=/opt/riscv
```

I tried the command above and it worked for the configure. But then when i run sudo make i have this error :
make[1]: *** [Makefile:13895: configure-target-libgcc] Error 1
If i check the log
configure:2489: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub riscv32-*-elf failed

Comment: You need to make a canadian cross compiler.  I suggest you get 'crosstool-ng'.  You will need an x86-64 compiler, an ARM cross compiler, and a risc-v cross compiler to make the ARM host/Risc-V cross. .  Read [the steps in build a compiler](https://crosstool-ng.github.io/docs/toolchain-construction/) and then trace out what type of compiler you need to perform the step.  If you have never built a compiler, give up now.  There are many compilers needed to build a canadian cross. You will need to create several compilers with similar configs. 
https://crosstool-ng.github.io/docs/toolchain-types/

Comment: Great thanks for the answer. So what are the option for in the compiler ? When you read GCC documentation it tells you about target and build option

Comment: I don't have many knowledge on compilers but also if building a compiler from a target to a specific build architecture why is it not possible for instance to just use an arm cross compiler to build a riscv cross compiler ?
I do have an arm cross compiler on my X86 machine and this git hold the source code of an riscv cross compiler : 
https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain
So can i just cross compile the riscv tool chain with the cross compiler arm.
Pertty tough to explain not sure I'm clear

Comment: The complexity is generally due to the 'libc'.  You do not compile the support libraries on the 'host' (ARM), but on the 'build' (x86).  Also, random compilers may have built-in option such as an OS, floating-point unit, ABI, etc.  You need these to match in the set of compilers you are targeting.  You also need the ARM libc to generate and link the compiler to run on the ARM.  An extremely simple compiler, with only code generation and no OS support whatsoever would simplify this.  But you have 'signals', 'math exceptions', etc that a conformant 'C' compiler needs to handle.

Comment: Okay i see, thanks for the answer, After a couple of hours and increasing the swap i managed to install the cross compiler directly on the arduino and i will not use it, too slow for want i want to do, thanks anyway :)